# MySQL String to Time Trouble

Tags: mysql

I have my time data stored in a MySQL Row called "timestart" and I have three rows containing the values `9:00am`, `10:00am`, `1:00pm` and I am trying to pull these out in a sorted order using the STR_TO_DATE function in my MySQL query. Here is the statement I am using:

`SELECT * FROM db.test WHERE name='Name' and dateusing='2015-10-21' ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE('timeusingstart', '%h:%i%p');`

It runs successfully but the rows get returned in the order of `10:00am`, `9:00am`, `1:00pm` when I need them to be sorted in the time sequential order. I used the `%h:%i%p` based on the information I found at [this documentation](http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/functions/str_to_date.php). Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not running `STR_TO_DATE()` on the column, you're running it on a string. Try removing the quotes from around `timeusingstart` and it should work.

By the way, [MySQL provides excellent documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) of all their functions!

```
mysql> create table test (test varchar(255));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> insert into test values('9:00am'), ('10:00am'), ('1:00pm');
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from test order by str_to_date(test, '%h:%i%p');
+---------+
| test    |
+---------+
| 9:00am  |
| 10:00am |
| 1:00pm  |
+---------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked brilliantly! I'm glad it was such a simple fix. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

Your statement is nearly correct. You need to remove the quotes around first parameter for STR_TO_DATE, it is parsing a string you provided, not a value of the column - timeusingstart.

```
STR_TO_DATE(timeusingstart, '%h:%i%p');
```